# Does dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)nickel(II) have a d⁰ electron count?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I am currently in dilemma because I'm trying to construct an octahedral splitting diagram for the $\ce{NiCl2(PPh3)2}$ complex. If the complex is $\mathrm{d^0}$ system, how would I determine whether the isomer is paramagnetic or diamagnetic?

Comment: Work out the nickel oxidation state as +2.  Can you count the $d$ electrons from there?

Comment: Oh, and this is not octahedral, unless there is some recent mathematical discovery of an octahedron with four rather than six vertices.

Comment: Considering the advised you gave, the d-count of the Ni2+ would be 8.